# Identify onItemClick for two different Gallery items in Android

Tags: android, android-gallery, onitemclicklistener, onitemclick

In my Activity, I have two **Gallery** items. I am implementing `OnItemClickListener` so I have to overwrite `onItemClick` method. I have set the listener as below,

```
eBookGallery.setOnItemClickListener(this);
eBrochuresGallery.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Those two Galleries load from two different **ArrayList** s. What I want is when I click the **eBookGallery** I want to get the data from **eBookArrayList** and when I click the **eBrochuresGallery** I want to get data from **eBrochureArrayList**.

How can I accomplish that task by using a single `onItemClick` method.

Thank you.

Comment: have both arraylist of same size or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter in the `onItemClick` method identifies the `AdapterView` on which this click happened.

```
public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
    if(parent == eBookGallery){
        //Click on an eBookGallery item
    }else if(parent == eBookBrochuresGallery){
        //Click on an eBookBrochuresGallery item
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh . I don't know why I didn't check on that parameter. I checked all the others except first one :-( Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 0):

When user click on any thing in android and we add click listener over it if user click on that then listener return a view the view is these object according to it we are able to get id from the view using findviewbyid. In the base of id we can identify then view.